# CSS style not functioning with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have a html file which has two images with areas mapped and marked by imagemapster. I want one of the images superimposed on another and the above image can be dragged around. Although I am quite close to achieving what I intend, something is going wrong. The image is drag-able but the default positon of this image is below the first image. I want it on top of the other. Also with a reduced opacity. When the page is reloaded, it seems to be superimposed for a fraction of a second. The statements inside the style is not working as supposed to. As much I can guess they are being overridden by jquery-ui or some other styles. Can anyone point out how to fix this?

locate.html.erb

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.imagemapster.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/threeddata.js"></script>

<style>
img {
    position: absolute;
}
#mainImage2 {
    opacity: 0.6;
}
</style>

<h1>Data Archival Library</h1>
</div>

<img id="mainImage" src="/assets/pic.png" usemap="#mark">
<map name="mark">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.write('<area href="#bottom" select="red1" shape="rect" coords="'+rowRackCoords.join(",")+'">');
    </script>
</map>

<div class="ui-widget-content" id="draggable">
<img id="mainImage2" src="/assets/unnamed.png" usemap="#mark2">
<map name="mark2">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.write('<area href="#top" select="red2" shape="rect" coords="'+shelfBoxCoords.join(",")+'">');
    </script>
</map>
</div>
```

.js

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $('#mainImage').mapster({
        singleSelect : false,
        clickNavigate: true,
        mapKey: 'select',
        fill : true, altImage: '/assets/pic2.png',
        areas : [{key : 'red1', selected : true,}],
    });
});

$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $('#mainImage2').mapster({
        singleSelect : false,
        clickNavigate: true,
        mapKey: 'select',
        fill : true,
        fillColor : '00FF00',
        fillOpacity : 0.5,
        areas : [{key : 'red2', selected : true}],
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {

    $(function () {
        $("#draggable").draggable();
    });
});
```

Comment: Make sure in your CSS that z-index of the image that you wish to be on top is larger than the z-index of the image that you wish to be on the bottom.

Comment: Still not working. The style inside html document is being overridden as far I can understand. I even tried !important, but that too does not help.

Answer (score 0):

First you should begin with only one `$(document).ready(function () {});` :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#mainImage').mapster({
        singleSelect : false,
        clickNavigate: true,
        mapKey: 'select',
        altImage: '/assets/pic2.png',
        areas : [{key : 'red1', selected : true,}],
    });
    $('#mainImage2').mapster({
        singleSelect : false,
        clickNavigate: true,
        mapKey: 'select',
        fillColor : '00FF00',
        fillOpacity : 0.5,
        areas : [{key : 'red2', selected : true}],
    });
    $("#draggable").draggable();
});
```

I haven't test it, but it will be a better start point.

*Edit : I removed `fill : true`, because it's the Mapster default value*

Comment: I could agree on that, but this does not fix the problem I state.